# How do I get the value of 'PAGE_CACHE_SIZE' that is mentioned in 'man mount'?

Tags: linux, debian, mount, kernel

How do I get the value of **PAGE_CACHE_SIZE** that is mentioned in `man mount`?

`man mount`:

> Mount options for tmpfs
>
> size=nbytes
>                 Override default maximum size of the filesystem.  The size is given in bytes, and rounded up to entire pages.  The default
>   is half  of  the  memory.   The  size
>                 parameter  also  accepts a suffix % to limit this tmpfs instance to that percentage of your physical RAM: the default, when
>   neither size nor nr_blocks is specified, is size=50%.
>
> nr_blocks=
>                 The same as size, but in blocks of PAGE_CACHE_SIZE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Page cache** - is the place in RAM where files are stored before writing to disk or after reading from disk. It's reduces delays for I/O operations to/from SSD, HDD, CD ...

**tmpfs** is the filesystem that lives in RAM permanently so **tmpfs** lives in **page cache**.

So **page cache** lives in RAM and consists of **pages**.

**Page** - is the minimum chunk of memory which OS can handle and it size depend on hardware (**MMU**(memory management unit) in CPU). All operations with memory usually rounded to page size.

Get page size (one of the way):

```
$ getconf PAGESIZE
4096
```

**PAGE_CACHE_SIZE** in `mount` command means count of **pages**. It's easy to check:

```
# mkdir /mnt/trash
# mount -t tmpfs -o nr_blocks=1 tmpfs /mnt/trash/
$ mount | grep trash
  tmpfs on /mnt/trash type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=4k)
$ df -h|grep trash
  tmpfs                4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /mnt/trash
```